# Want to copy oracle data to hadoop

Tags: oracle, hadoop, ambari

The tutorial in the link, mentioned below .

[java-spark-tutorial](https://blog.matthewrathbone.com/2015/12/28/java-spark-tutorial.html)

I have loaded data in oracle . Now i need to import it into hadoop . I am new to hadoop . I am familiar with Ambari .Can anyone please suggest how can we load data from oracle to hadoop using ambari tool ?

Comment: Use [Sqoop](https://sqoop.apache.org/)

Comment: Ambari is a provisioning/admin tool for the cluster, its not a way to move data.  Sqoop is probably the best option.

Answer (score 0):

You can import rows from oracle to hadoop using sqoop. Typical command would be

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:<username>/<password>@<IP address>:1521:<db name>  --username <username> -P --table <database name>.<table name> --columns "<column names>" --target-dir  <target directory path in hdfs> -m 1
```